# Is there a way to make a multiplayer dice game where the players have turns rolling and the scores tally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module

I'm trying to make a code for a multiplayer dice rolling game where the user can input how many players. 
I want the code to repeat until a player reaches 100 points and go on a cycle between all the players.

I've tried all sorts of functions/modules for this and asked peers and some teachers, searched online for this and all over stack overflow but couldn't find an answer.

```
playerPoints = {}
toRoll = ""
minPlayers = 2
maxPlayers = 4
winner = 100
double1 = 25

def players(numberOfPlayers):
    numberOfPlayers = 0
    while numberOfPlayers not in (str(i) for i in range (minPlayers,maxPlayers)):
        numberOfPlayers = int(numberOfPlayers)
        for i in range(numberOfPlayers):
            playerPoints["score{}".format(i+1)] = 0
        return numberOfPlayers

def diceroll():
    die1 = randint(1,6)
    die2 = randint(1,6)
    return die1, die2
    roll = 0
    while roll not in (str(i) for i in toRoll):
        roll = input("Press enter to roll both dice")
        if roll == toRoll:
            print(str(die1) + " and " + str(die2))
            break
```

I want the code to continue however I am stuck at this point where the code only asks how many players are there and then breaks.
[image: this is how the code "breaks"]

I called the function by doing:

```
numberOfPlayers = input("How many players are there? (2-4)")
players(numberOfPlayers)
diceroll(die1, die2)
roll()
```

Comment: What do you means by your code breaks. Does it stop and wait? Does it give an error? If it stops and waits, that is because you have an input statement, so you'll have to give some input, if an error occurs, please show the error.

Comment: I think what he means is that the code just stops there and doesn't wait

Comment: Yeah @EnochHan is right like the code doesn't carry on from there, no errors.

Comment: Could you guys like help me get past this "stop" and then tell me how to make a loop which cycles the players? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, like I said, if it stops on the `numberOfPlayers = input("How many players are there? (2-4)")` part, then your code waits until you give it an input. So to move on, just give it an input.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the added picture, now I get what you mean by breaking. However, I tested your code, and it works fine for me. It will return `2` when `2` is  given in the input. How do you call the function?

Comment: Remove `numberOfPlayers = 0`.

Comment: Do what @snakecharmerb says. And also, you are giving `die1` and `die2` as parameters to the `diceroll` function, which takes zero arguments, that won't work. Also, is your original problem still happening now that you've changed your code?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the `return` statement in `diceroll()`.  This means that the `while` loop never runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible fix for your problem

There are all kinds of `return` statements in your code which makes it impossible for some code to be executed. Like in the `diceroll` function where you return `die1` and `die2` in:

```
return die1, die2
```

The code after that line is never exectuted because the function returns some values.

You say that you execute the function like so:

```
numberOfPlayers = input("How many players are there? (2-4)")
players(numberOfPlayers)
diceroll(die1, die2)
roll()
```

However, the `diceroll` function takes zero parameters, while you give it two (`die1` and `die2`), this won't work. Also I don't see a `roll` function in your code, so that will give you an error as well.

## How I would have done it

So, I know StackOverflow is not the place where we write code for you. But since there were all kinds of things in your code that I found weird. I have rewritten the code as how I would have done it:

```
import random

playerPoints = []
minPlayers = 2
players = 0
maxscore = 100
amountOfDice = 2
gameRound = 0

def setPlayers():
    while True:
        players = input("How many players are playing?\n")
        if players.isdigit():
            players = int(players)
            if minPlayers <= players:
                for i in range(players):
                    playerPoints.append(0)
                return players

def diceroll(player, amountOfDice):
    throw = 0
    print("\tPlayer {0}s turn:".format(player + 1))
    for i in range(amountOfDice):
        die = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("\t\tPlayer {0} has thrown die {1} which landed on {2}".format(player + 1, i + 1, die))
        throw += die

    playerPoints[player] += throw
    print("\tPlayer {0}s score is now: {1}".format(player + 1, playerPoints[player]))
    return throw

def checkWin(maxscore):
    for player in range(players):
        if (playerPoints[player] >= maxscore):
            print("Player {0} wins!".format(player + 1))
            return True

    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    players = setPlayers()
    while True:
        gameRound += 1
        print("Round: {0}".format(gameRound))
        for i in range(players):
            diceroll(i, amountOfDice)
        if (checkWin(maxscore)):
            break
```

Now, first off, I removed some restrictions in the `players` function (and changed the name to `setPlayers`). Your code didn't have a check if the input was a number, which could result in an error. I also removed the restriction of 4 players, because the code works with every amount (if 2 or higher ofcourse).

The `diceroll` function now takes the player that will roll as an argument as well as the amount of dice that will be rolled.

I also added the `checkWin` function which checks if a player has won. It takes the maximum score as an argument.

Now this probably isn't the fastest code, however I think its understandable. If you have any questions about it, feel free to ask.

Comment: Wow this code is great I really like how it functions, but I would like the user to press enter if they would like to roll, instead of having the whole code run at once. I know I'm asking for a lot but I'm still a beginner to python so I would really appreciate that. I will add some more code that I would like to work! - never mind the code that I want is still there, I really would like the players to take turns to roll the die.

Comment: If you want I can post another question with my entire code on it for you to see

Comment: btw, what does  print("\tPlayer {0}s turn:".format(player + 1)) the {0} mean?

Comment: @Anonymous I will let you implement taking turns yourself, so you also learn something from this. Just know that checking for an enter input can be achieved like so: `if not input("Some text"): # Code when enter has been pressed`.

Comment: @Anonymous, the `.format()` function after a string takes all the `{}` from the string and places the variable given to the `format()` function at the place of `{}`. The `0` in between is not mandatory, especially not when only one variable is given, but I like to do it anyway. More on the format function with some examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/).